# @SpringBootTest in Junit 5 integration test has UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: spring-boot, junit5

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    public UserService svc;
   ...
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;
   ...
}
```

Dao is a simple repository interface.

Test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {UserController.class, UserService.class, UserDao.class})
public class UserIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserController controller;

    @Test
    public void createUserTest() {
        User integration = new User();
        integration.setName("integration");
        integration.setEmail("initial@integration.com");
        integration.setRoles(new ArrayList<String>());

        Response response = controller.addUser(integration.getName(), integration.getEmail(), integration.getRoles());
        Assertions.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Error output:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:97)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:743)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'svc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating ...
```

If I run the main application directly, everything is fine. But I can't do testing.

I've already added all bean class in the @SpringBootTest as other thread says, but it does not resolve the problem.
Does anyone have an idea about the reason and solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **@SpringBootTest** directly or point to your {your-starter-application-class} in the **@SpringBootTest(classes={Your-Starter-Application-Class})**, remove the controller,service and dao, because classes in the annotated SpringBootTest is used for loading an ApplicationContext, if no explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested **@Configuration** classes

```
@SpringBootTest
```

or

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Your-Starter-Application-Class})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **@SpringBootTest** should be enough to load the ApplicationContext. 
Also for integration testing of REST APIs you should be using **TestRestTemplate** to execute your REST APIs rather than autowiring the Controller. The instance of TestRestTemplate can be autowired in test classes annotated with @SpringBootTest.